# How to wrap a sentence into mutiple lines?

Tags: android

With help of this link I am able to enter text and its working fine http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/#comments

But How to wrap the huge sentence to multiple lines

Mainly i need help in this part of code

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        //turn antialiasing on
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        canvas.drawText("Style.FILL.show the full complete text Thanks dude..I am searching for this thing since last three days. But no where they have given as simple as you given ", 75, 110, paint);
```

Getting the whole sentence in single line but I wanted to see it in multiple lines

How is it possible?

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use "\n" to each time you want to break the line

Comment: am getting the text from DB so how can i give \n for every field each time??

Comment: @Yume117: even am unable to see more the 9 characters in the output

Answer (score 0):

there are many options.

one would be to separate by "+" :

```
canvas.drawText("Style.FILL.show the full complete text Thanks dude.."+
"I am searching for this thing since last three days. But no where"+
" they have given as simple as you given ", 75, 110, paint);
```

another one would be to put the string into the strings.xml . this way you don't have "junk" in the code, plus you could add qualifiers for when to use each string (for example localizations) .

---

EDIT: i thought you meant that it annoys you in the code. now i understand that you need it working in the app itself.

the next code will take any text and will make it have word wrap according to a rectangle that you give it. in case the text is too long even for the max lines specified, the text will be truncated. it also supports text alignment.

here's the code:

```
// TODO make this whole class more customizable (text size, text color,gravity...), maybe using textView
// TODO make this code better somehow. the positioning is very weird.
final Rect rect = ...;
// find the truncated text to show based on the max lines that are allowed:
StaticLayout sl;
int pivot, maxCharactersCount = mTextToShow.length(), minCharactersCount = 0;
sl = new StaticLayout(mTextToShow, mTextPaint, rect.width(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 1, false);
int lineCount = sl.getLineCount();
if (lineCount > mMaxLines)
    while (true) {
        pivot = (maxCharactersCount + minCharactersCount) / 2;
        final String text = mTextToShow.substring(0, pivot);
        sl = new StaticLayout(text, mTextPaint, rect.width(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 1, false);
        lineCount = sl.getLineCount();
        if (lineCount <= mMaxLines) {
            minCharactersCount = pivot;
            if (maxCharactersCount <= minCharactersCount + 1)
                break;
        } else
            maxCharactersCount = pivot;
    }
if (lineCount == 0)
    return;
// get the bounding width of the text (of all lines):
int maxTextWidth = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i)
    maxTextWidth = (int) Math.max(maxTextWidth, sl.getLineWidth(i));
// some initializations...
final float textHeight = mTextPaint.getTextSize();
final float totalTextHeight = textHeight * lineCount;
final float rotation = getRotation();
final String truncatedText = sl.getText().toString();
// calculate where to start the drawing:
final float yCenter = (rect.bottom + rect.top) / 2;
final float yStart = yCenter - totalTextHeight / 2;
int startX;
switch (mAlign) {
case CENTER:
    startX = (rect.left + rect.right) / 2;
    break;
case RIGHT:
    startX = rect.right;
    break;
case LEFT:
default:
    startX = rect.left;
    break;
}
// start drawing:
canvas.save();
if (rotation != 0)
    canvas.rotate(rotation);
canvas.translate(startX, yStart);
// for each line, draw it in the corresponding location, based on its width and which line it is:
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i) {
    final int lineTextWidth = (int) sl.getLineWidth(i);
    final String lineText = truncatedText.substring(sl.getLineStart(i), sl.getLineEnd(i));
    int xToDrawRelativeToStart = 0;
    switch (mAlign) {
    case CENTER:
        xToDrawRelativeToStart = -lineTextWidth / 2;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        xToDrawRelativeToStart = -lineTextWidth;
        break;
    case LEFT:
    default:
        xToDrawRelativeToStart = 0;
        break;
    }
    canvas.drawText(lineText, xToDrawRelativeToStart, textHeight * (i + 1), mTextPaint);
}
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: i thought you meant that the way it looks in the code is annoying. if you want it to work on the android app itself, you need to add "\n" between lines. for example : String t = "hello\nworld"; but maybe it won't work with paint, so you need to divide the string yourself, and move the canvas after each line. would you like me to show you some code ? i've even made it be able to have gravity...

Comment: ok, i've posted some code . it should help you as it's a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your text manually, in the code (as suggested by others), but the thing is that in your IDE you see your text in monospace font, while the font you use to draw text is not monospace, so the lines will not be equal:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed vehicula dui.

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed vehicula dui.`

You see the difference.

I suggest you use [`Paint.breakText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float,%20float%5B%5D%29).